# Android Class Tree

Tags: android

I'm fairly new to programming with the Android SDK. Was wondering if a program existed that shows the class and package tree with the source code in an easy to read format.

Was thinking something like [UnCodeX](http://uncodex.elmuerte.com/) but for Android rather than UnrealScript.

Also preferably for Linux?

Comment: are you looking for an [IDE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integrated_development_environment) ? if so [eclipse](http://www.eclipse.org/) is the prefered android IDE..

Comment: looking for something that I can use to search through the Android source